# Choice of I vs we in job applications and grants

Tags: mathematics, funding, job-search, writing, writing-style

In mathematics, it is standard to use "we" instead of "I", even in single author papers.
Is this the case for job and grant applications as well?
For instance, suppose I wish to say something to the effect of:

> To study (problem), **I** will extend (technique) from **my** past work [citation].

Here are several considerations, although I'm sure there are many more:

- I want to emphasize that I am the one driving the proposed work forward. Using "we" in place of "I" emphasizes this less. On the other hand, I do intend to collaborate with others on this work.
- The past work is not mine alone, even if I was the "main" contributor (whatever that means). I could omit "my" entirely, but the fact that (technique) is something I've worked on before is important in justifying why I am suited to study (problem), and I don't think people will necessarily take the time to read the reference entry. I could also be more explicit and say something like "past collaborations", but this comes at the cost of wordiness.

TLDR: Is there a convention for pronoun use in job applications and grants? Are there any resources which discuss best practices for writing choices like this in job and grant applications?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how universal this is, but I have generally observed people using "I" in job applications, and "the PI" in grant applications, in place of the "we" that is used in papers.

Comment: In math usually there is no PI.

Comment: @quarague NSF, the primary funding source for math in the US, does refer to the lead person on a grant as the PI.

Answer (score 1):

In general using "I"  in job and grant applications is perfectly fine.

For grant applications one possible alternative is to introduce an acronym or short name for your project (this often mandatory for EU grant proposals). Many instances of "I will do this/I will do that", can then be replaced by "PROJECT will do this/ PROJECT will do that". Besides getting around the sometimes awkward use of "I", this also helps emphasize that funding the project is essential to get these things done.

(The use of "I" on the other hand can help emphasize that you are a crucial ingredient in bring the proposed work to a success.)

Comment: This is just my personal taste, but I think using the acronyms will look somewhat ridiculous in a non-European context, especially if you really mean things you will do yourself and not as part of a team.  The only context I've every seen these used is ERC grants.